# Individually Compiling SCSS Files in Gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a list of SCSS partials organized by components that I am trying to compile individually with Gulp, but can't figure out how to do so.

Here is a partial list of files that I want to compile:

```
_header.scss
_button.scss
_navigation.scss
```

And I want to output these files in the same directory as

```
header.css
button.css
navigation.css
```

I am using `gulp-sass` in order to compile **all** of my SCSS files into a single file like so:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp
    // Find all `.scss` files from the `stylesheets/` folder
    .src('./src/stylesheets/**/*.scss')
    // Run Sass on those files
    .pipe(sass({
      style: 'expanded',
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    // Write the resulting CSS in the output folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/stylesheets'))
});
```

Is there a way to create a separate Gulp task that would compile and output each file in a directory individually instead of combining them into one file at the end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rename the partial files remove the leading underscore.  Sass normally wont generate the output file if the file name starts with _xxx.scss.

[Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

> The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and
>   that it should not be generated into a CSS file.

You can rename the file to xxx.scss and still import into other files like partials.